# Can I partition a DB table after it is already created on SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, partitioning

Most examples dealing with table partitions, create the table on the partition scheme.

For example:

```
create table SomeTable
(
  Id int not null ,
  DueDate DateTime not null
) on MyPartitionScheme(DueDate)
```

Where MyPartitionScheme is a predefined partition scheme.

If I have a table that already exists, possibly with data with it. Can I "alter" it to use the partition scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [*Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Implementation and Maintenance*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562271X):

> 1. Create a partition function
> 2. Create a partition scheme
> 3. Drop the existing clustered index
> 4. Re-create the clustered index on the partition scheme

Comment: Won't this just partition the clustered index and not the table storage itself?

Comment: the table is stored in the clustered index.  that's what a clustered index is

Answer (score 0):

lookup ALTER TABLE SWITCH TO PARTITION in BOL

Comment: Does this just move the data on one partition to another table?

Answer (score 0):

In [Partitioned Tables and Indexes in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146.aspx) clearly states:

> *"By defining a clustered index on a partition scheme, you will effectively partition the table after the load. **This is also a great way of partitioning an existing table**. To create the same table as a nonpartitioned table, and create the clustered index as a partitioned clustered index, replace the ON clause in the create table with a single filegroup destination. Then, create the clustered index on the partition scheme after the data is loaded."*